# How to scroll to specific point on DOM using useRef()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to access a specific point on DOM using useRef() from a dropdown.
at the moment I have implemented the logic using `#` ID but I want to use useRef().

Also to be mentioned: I don't have access to the App.js to
pass the `ref` to other components.

dropdown.js

```
export default function DropDown() {
  const ScrollToTitle = (e) => {
    const title = e.target.value;
    window.location = '#' + title;
// how to access the ref in here insted of # ID?
  };
  return (
    <select onChange={ScrollToTitle}>
      <option>First </option>
      <option>Second </option>
      <option>Third </option>
      <option>Another </option>
      <option>Somthing </option>
    </select>
  );
}
```

I have a couple of titles on the App but as an example here is one of them:

```
export default function First() {

  const titleRef = useRef(); // what I wan to use

  return (
    <div id='First'>
      <h1 ref={titleRef}>First </h1> // is this correct ?
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How and from where to access the `titleRef`?
to be mentioned again : I don't have access to the App.js to
pass the `ref` to other components.

and I have a live example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cpezfb

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll to an element using its ref (such as `titleRef`) by doing the following:

```
titleRef.current.scrollIntoView();
```

A more complete solution to your particular issue is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ycwepv), where I updated your code to work for the `First` and `Second` components.

The idea is that the refs to the components you want to scroll to should be shared, thus defined in the parent. The refs should be assigned to the different components, then the dropdown can make use of them for the navigation.

Ideally, you should avoid the use of the strings "First", "Second" etc as keys and use constants for instance (by defining the values as constant such as `const FIRST = "First";` then using those constants so that your code is easier to maintain.

Comment: should I add this in dropdown.js?

Comment: My bad, I assumed that all of your code is within the same component, since your Dropdown needs access to the ref. I have updated your code to have the refs in the parent component of both the Dropdown and the other components (First, Second, etc...) and made it work for First and second as a example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ycwepv

Comment: I will update my answer with the link and a little explanation of what I changed

Comment: Although your answer is correct, in my case, I don't have access to App.js to pass the ref to other components. Do you think there is any workaround for that?

Comment: Another approach would be to use some state within your app, if you have access to that, such as a Context to have the refs accessible to all the components. Otherwise, using the the anchor links that you initially tried is a very good solution if you are constrained, an improvement would be to use constants for the values so you don't need to worry about the links breaking if a value doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem with `useRef` is you did not share the mutual states between section components and the dropdown list component, so if you want to call `useRef`, you need to share that with all your related components.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kzmzip?file=src%2FApp.js) is the full implementation of how to call `useRef` for your case

Firstly, I used `forwardRef` to pass the ref to a specific element in your section components (in this case, the ref is the title element). If you don't understand what it is, you can read [this doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

export default React.forwardRef(function First(props, ref) {
  return (
    <div id='First'>
      <h1 ref={ref}>First </h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
})
```

And then in `App.js`, I defined `useRef` for a list of refs (not single) for all sections. I also used [liftting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) technique for `scrollToTitle`

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import First from './components/First';
import Second from './components/Second';
import Third from './components/Third';
import Another from './components/Another';
import Somthing from './components/Somthing';
import DropDown from './components/DropDown';

export default function App() {
  const titleRefs = useRef({});
  const scrollToTitle = (e) => {
    const title = e.target.value;
    titleRefs.current[title].scrollIntoView();
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <DropDown scrollToTitle={scrollToTitle} />
      <First ref={(node) => (titleRefs.current['First'] = node)} />
      <Second ref={(node) => (titleRefs.current['Second'] = node)} />
      <Third ref={(node) => (titleRefs.current['Third'] = node)} />
      <Another ref={(node) => (titleRefs.current['Another'] = node)} />
      <Somthing ref={(node) => (titleRefs.current['Somthing'] = node)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

BUT I think you used `window.location = '#' + title;` is not that bad. With the above implementation, your URL won't have `#id` to access that section directly by URL, so many of us still prefer using `#` instead of `ref`.

Comment: as I don't have access to App.js to pass the ref to other components, is there a workaround to implement it?

Comment: hmm I think it's impossible withour `App.js` access. Because all your components are used in `App.js`. If you use your components in a container component and call that container one in `App.js`, we can have an open path for solutions.